# Convert ogg to mp3 in batch

Tags: command-line

I have a huge collection of about 3k folders and have ogg files in each of them. I would like to do a convertion to mp3 for all the folders in a batch. I have 1 folder as a main directory, 12 folders subs and then a ton of folders in each of the 12 folders. Is there a way that I can convert all the folders keeping the same name and the copy to be made in the same folder as the original?

Comment: Please see here my (simple) ogg to mp3 conversion script: https://askubuntu.com/questions/442997/how-can-i-convert-audio-from-ogg-to-mp3/1064524#1064524

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You need a commandline tool to do the conversion. I'm sure one exists, but have never used one myself. Then use this oneliner from within your main folder:

```
for /r %%f in (*.ogg) do ogg_to_mp3 "%%f" "%%~dpnf.mp3"
```

To explain the magic %%~dpnf: This is used to extract parts from %%f (the full filename of the ogg file), where d is the drive letter, p the path and n the filename without the extension.

Use single % signs when executing directly from the commandline, double when executing from a batch file.

**Edit**: I now see that you didn't specify which OS your are on. This solution is for Windows.